# Query for mongoexport cant read $or, $gt, ISODate()

Tags: linux, mongodb, bash, mongodb-query, mongoexport

Hi i have bash script for exporting mongodb data, here is the script

```
#!/bin/sh

DATE_NOW=$(date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z)
DATE_EXPIRED=$(date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z -d "$DATE_NOW - 3 month")
echo $DATE_EXPIRED
echo '{ 
        "$or": [ 
            { "creationTime": { "$gt": "ISODate('\'$DATE_EXPIRED\'')" } },
            { "requestTime": { "$gt": "ISODate('\'$DATE_EXPIRED\'')"} }
        ]
    }'
DB=nexuspay
DB_COLLECTIONS=$(mongosh "mongodb://localhost:27017/$DB?authSource=admin" --norc --quiet --eval "db.getCollectionNames().join(' ')")
for collection in $DB_COLLECTIONS; do
    echo "Exporting $DB/$collection ..."
    mongoexport --db=$DB --collection=$collection --query '{ 
        "$or":[ 
            { "creationTime":{ "$gt":"ISODate('\'$DATE_EXPIRED\'')" } },
            { "requestTime":{ "$gt":"ISODate('\'$DATE_EXPIRED\'')"} }
        ]
    }' --out=backup-$(date +"%d%m%Y")/$collection.json 

    # echo "Deleting $DB/$collection ..."
    # mongosh "mongodb://localhost:27017/$DB?authSource=admin" --norc --quiet --eval "db.$collection.deleteMany({})"
done

echo "BACKUP AND CLEAN DATABASE COMPLETE"
```

This is the result
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCOv1.png)
but its not what i expected, this is what the expected result in mongodb UI
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8FTM.png)

I noticed that the query is different, but when i want to change it to the correct one (which is in image2), i got an error

```
2023-04-25T22:59:23.640+0800    Failed: error parsing query as Extended JSON: error decoding key 0: invalid JSON input. Position: 57. Character: I
```

anyone have solution? thanks

Comment: Welcome. Please DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.—copy or type the text into the question and format it properly. Images are uselessly large, not searchable, not copy-paste-able,... Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You can also read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557) for a long list of reasons.

Comment: You could try using `"$date"` like shown in the [`mongoexport` `--query` example](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoexport/#std-option-mongoexport.--query).

Answer (score 0):

`ISODate()` is a function in mongo shell `mongosh`, it does not exist in `mongoexport`

Try this one:

```
--query '{ 
    "$or":[ 
        { "creationTime":{ "$gt": { "$date": "'$DATE_EXPIRED'" } } },
        { "requestTime":{ "$gt": { "$date": "'$DATE_EXPIRED'" } } }
    ]
}'
```